# How To Convert From Decimal to Octal Without Changing The Digits Of The Number? (python)

Tags: python

Is it possible to convert a decimal number (an integer) to an octal number without changing the numbers?

For example, is it possible to take the number 221 in decimal, and turn it into 221 in octal?

But instead of it being 221, I can do it with any number?

Comment: You mean you want to _interpret_ 221 as octal, meaning 2 * 8^2 + 2* 8^1 + 1 * 8^0?

Comment: No, I meant I would want to convert the value so that it would equal 221 in octal, whatever that number in decimal would be

Comment: @Chris I meant I would want to change the number so that it is equal to 221 in octal, and  it would be equal to 335 in decimal, but it's listed as 221.

Comment: So... you want to interpret 221 as octal :-).

Comment: @Chris could you look into my last question? It would be really helpful, and it provides more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Octal 221 (`0o221`) is actually equal to *145* in decimal, not 335:

```py
>>> 2 * (8 ** 2) + 2 * (8 ** 1) + 1 * (8 ** 0)
145
>>> 0o221 == 145
True
```

I think this is what you want:

```py
>>> int(str(221), base=8)
145
```

`str(221)` converts `221` in decimal to a string: `"221"`. [`int("221", base=8)` converts the string back to an integer in base 8](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int).

Comment: Thank you Chris, but could you help me out on my previous post? The only test case for that one that is failing right now is 10, 10, 10, could you help me figure out why?

Comment: Also I tested this, and it worked, but there's still one issue left with my last post.

Answer (score 0):

335 in octal is 221 in decimal. To switch between octal and decimal you can use `octal(decimal_number)` or `int(octal_number, 8)`

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, but could you answer my last post? That's where the root of the issue is coming from.